# Transform function and curser: pointer not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make it so when a user clicks on a triangle/the text next to it, the triangle turns and shows a PHP variable under it. However, when I do this it does not appear to work and the cursor pointer does not even appear. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Code is below

```js
function triangleChange1() {
 var x = document.getElementById("triangle1")
 
 var y = document.getElementById("bID")
 
  if (y.style.display === "none") {
 x.style.transform =  "rotate(90deg)";
    y.style.display = "block"; 
  } 
  else {
 x.style.transform =  "rotate(-90deg)";
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.triangle1/*, .triangle2, .triangle3, .triangle4, .triangle5*/{ 
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 6px solid transparent;
 border-left: 14px solid #555;
 border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
 margin-left: -25px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle1" id="triangle1" onclick="triangleChange1()"></div> <div class = "balance" onclick="triangleChange1()"> Student Card Balance </div><br>


<div class = "bID" id="bID"> $<?php echo $Balance;?> </div><br>
```

Comment: I see the `$` symbol is seen on click, what is it you need?

Comment: I think its working.... When I clicked student card it shows/display ```$``` which is php part... I think snippet won't show php part show it gives ```$```, else it should give. I think ```$``` is useless in your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a triangle shape but you have to give the size property for the `div` to be seen, I guess you're missing that.

```js
function triangleChange1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("triangle1")

  var y = document.getElementById("bID")

  if (y.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg)";
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.triangle1
/*, .triangle2, .triangle3, .triangle4, .triangle5*/

{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  margin-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle1" id="triangle1" onclick="triangleChange1()"></div>
<div class="balance" onclick="triangleChange1()"> Student Card Balance </div><br>


<div class="bID" id="bID"> $
  <?php echo $Balance;?> </div><br>
```

Comment: `getElementById` is not used to select elements with classes.

Comment: OP has both ID and Class of same name, Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I apologize, my mistake.

Comment: Happens! Cheers.